# Chromebook stopped routing OpenVPN

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server (on pfSense) running, to which I connect with my Chromebook to access certain private resources. This was working great. However, since a couple of days, it stopped working as before. I can still connect to the VPN, and using crosh I can ping the internal ip of the OpenVPN server. However, no other traffic is sent over the VPN link, while normally it should take all traffic and breakout from the datacenter. The routing table does not include a route to the OpenVPN server for traffic, so I think that's the issue, but I'm not certain on how to resolve this.

With a Windows computer, the VPN tunnel still works completely as expected.

It seems a bug in the Chromebook that was introduced in a recent update, but I don't know where I could find that out. Anybody have any help for me?

Comment: Pls post the Chromebook routing table when on the VPN.